# Arduino Uno upload fail

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I face an error while uploading the code to my Arduino UNO

avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\.\COM6"

Also the "L" light is also glowing on the board.

Comment: Further information is needed. But probably your Arduino interface is at a different port.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reset the Arduino with its Reset button, if this doesn't work refresh the USB drivers and do check the COM port. This should work.

Comment: I have tried but doesn't work. It may be the fault of my arduino board.

Comment: Try connecting Arduino board to another system that has driver and IDE installed and note if it works properly, if it doesn't than might be your Arduino board is malfunctioned , possible reasons could be the Microcontroller itself or it could be FTDI chip.